# How do I add Header in rest service which calls using HttpWebRequest with GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, http, wcf-data-services

How do I add a header value while calling a restful service using `GET` method in `Silverlight`?

Comment: are you referring to your server response or your client request?

Answer (score 1):

You can create HttpWebRequest via ClientHttp, e.g.:

```
var url = new Uri("your url");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(url);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Pragma] = "no-cache";
request.Method = "GET";
```